# How to Remove a PFRelation

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

Currently, I can create a `PFRelation` between the current user and the mainUser (user to be followed).

```
PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("following").addObject(mainUser)
PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if (success) {
    } else {
         println(error)
         // error adding follow relation
    }

}
```

How can I "unfollow" or remove the `PFRelation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically identical to what you have now. `PFRelation` has both `addObject` and `removeObject` methods that you can call and then re-save the relationship (by saving the owning object).

Comment: Wow, I thought parse had restrictions on removing existing relations that I didn't try the most obvious solution.